# TYPO3 tx_ttaddress: How to change locallang of pagebrowser

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I would like to change the "previous/next" Text of `tx_ttaddress` page browser. I think this extension uses the paginate viewhelper from fluid. Is it possible to overwrite the labels via `typoscript` `Locallang`? Can someone tell me how it works? 
The following way doesn't work:

```
plugin.tx_ttaddress {
  _LOCAL_LANG.default {
    paginate_next = TEST
    paginate_previous = TEST
   }
}
```

Comment: I can confirm this issue with TYPO3 9.5.7 and tt_address 4.3.0. I've created a [bug report](https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/tt_address/issues/221).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pagination is rendered by fluid, therefore the TypoScript must be a bit different

```
plugin.tx_fluid {
  _LOCAL_LANG.default {
    widget.pagination.next = TEST
   }
}
```